# I have create a nodemailer serivce, but i got the error below.

Tags: hotmail, nodemailer

my code is

```
var wellknown = require("nodemailer-wellknown")
var config = wellknown("Hotmail");
console.log(config)

config.auth = {
 user:"ilovesunny112@hotmail.com",
 pass:"XXXXX"
}
```

but finally i got the error below.

> { [Error: Invalid login]
>     code: 'EAUTH',
>     response: '535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed',
>     responseCode: 535 }